# What does the dispatch tag mean?  Is a tag merge needed here?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Recently I had a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782826/confusing-method-bindings) and it was re tagged to dispatch. But it has only 3 followers with no description.

What does this tag [dispatch](/questions/tagged/dispatch) even mean?

Should the tags [dynamic-dispatch](/questions/tagged/dynamic-dispatch) and [dynamic-binding](/questions/tagged/dynamic-binding) be synonyms of [dispatch](/questions/tagged/dispatch)?

Comment: Probably http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch, but I'll have a look.

Comment: “Dynamic binding” can also mean “dynamic scoping”, but from a quick glance at the current [tag:dynamic-binding] questions, the tag currently means dynamic dispatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dispatch](/questions/tagged/dispatch) can apparently mean anything that the word “dispatch” can mean. There's method dispatch, which [dynamic-dispatch](/questions/tagged/dynamic-dispatch) is a kind of, but also [event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756331/chrome-dispatching-wheel-event) [dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635138/is-it-possible-to-dispatch-events-on-regular-objects-not-dom-ones), [function dispatch (in a non-OO context)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421599/how-to-monkey-patch-a-generic-type-tag-function-table), [TCP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040545/how-to-dispatch-network-requests-to-the-geographically-closest-server), some [Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522449/wordpress-no-dispatch) concept that I know nothing about, an [HTTP library called Dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113516/what-is-a-simple-way-to-receive-snmp-traps-in-scala), etc. There doesn't seem to be much value in this tag.

I recommend to go over the list, and if you understand what a question is about and can come up with better tags, go for it.